# Redactor denied tags replacement?

Tags: redactor

Has anyone found a replacement for:

```
deniedTags: ['p'],
paragraphize: false
```

I can't find a way to strip the pesky `<p>` tag anymore, on Redactor II.

Answer (score 2):

I guess with Redactor II you "manually" have to make sure you cannot create those tags with buttons/shortcuts or by pasting in rich text.

- Button configuration works with the `formatting` and `formattingAdd` settings.
- [Paste config settings](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/paste/) were added with Redactor II 1.2 (Craft 2.bla), the ones you're probably interested in are `pasteBlockTags` and `pasteInlineTags`.

Redactor II deprecated the `paragraphize` setting and automatically wraps each paragraph in `<p>` tags. If you also want to prevent `<p>` tags, removing them on a template level using a Twig filter like [`striptags`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) is probably your best bet at the moment (→ see [Redactor II Craft 2.5 Prevent Paragraphs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13183/125)).