# Redactor II issue - adding completely random linebreaks to pasted text

Tags: redactor, wysiwyg

(This is *not* a duplicate of [Redactor II Craft 2.5 Prevent Paragraphs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/redactor-ii-craft-2-5-prevent-paragraphs))

I am trying to paste in text from LibreOffice and the text ends up in Redactor II with, as far as I can tell, **completely random** linebreaks. It is not limited to a single document, but happens with any .odt or .doc I attempt to use. It's adding multiple linebreaks within a single paragraph, sometimes after every word - and they are getting added as [br]s to the HTML source, so it's not just some sort of visual artifact.

My client is, as you might imagine, furious with the new behavior. Has anyone else seen anything like this? Is there a fix? In the meantime I am using the "Redactor I" plugin by P&T, but that's not sustainable.